# Little help about url routing in mobile apps

Tags: mobile, url-routing, qooxdoo

Run this little qooxdoo mobile example, press "Popup" button, and then press 2 times the mobile hardware's back button (or browser's back button).

Run again the example, press "Popup" button, press "Close Popup" button, and then press the mobile hardware's back button (or browser's back button).

Why the popup show again?
What am I doing wrong, what is my misunderstanding? I need the "Close Popup" button work like the hardware back button. Why the behavior is different? How solve my mistake?

Thanks (sorry my poor english)

```
var routing = qx.core.Init.getApplication().getRouting();

var btnClose = new qx.ui.mobile.form.Button("Close Popup");
btnClose.addListener("tap", function() {
  routing.back();
});
var popup = new qx.ui.mobile.dialog.Popup(btnClose);
popup.setModal(true);
popup.setTitle("A Popup");

var page1 = new qx.ui.mobile.page.NavigationPage();
page1.setTitle("Page 1");
page1.addListener("initialize", function() {
  var button = new qx.ui.mobile.form.Button("Popup");
  page1.getContent().add(button);

  button.addListener("tap", function() {
    routing.executeGet("/popup");
  });
});

var manager = new qx.ui.mobile.page.Manager(false);
manager.addDetail([page1]);

routing.onGet("/", page1.show, page1);
routing.onGet("/popup", popup.show, popup);

routing.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

window.history.back() instead of routing.back(), the solution